# How can I derive the word "API" to a verb?

Tags: verbs, derivational-morphology

The word [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) stands for Application Programming Interface.

Normally I would say:

- I developed an API of something.
- I designed a set of APIs of something.

Since the word API is so common in the programmer's society. So I'm wondering if I can create a new verb derived from API so that the above sentences can be re-write like this:

- I **APIfied** something.

Comment: Please, do not do this.

Comment: You can do whatever you like.  The NSA *probably* won't come and get you in the middle of the night.

Comment: I wouldn't hesitate to say "APIify" or some such in informal speech or in an informal note or email.  When said to your coworkers and others in the industry the meaning is perfectly clear.  However, for any sort of formal communication one should use one of your "normally" phrases, or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a few pieces of confusion here.

It's not accurate to say that you [blank]ed an API *of* something. You'd say that you provided an API *for* something. So creating a verb for that is as bit awkward.

You don't transmogrify something by putting an API around it, so there's no real "APIfication" going on. You *wrap* it and you *expose* an interface so others can act on it. That action is *interfacing*, which is the *I* in API.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are much better off not trying to concoct such a verb.

Consider that people have been writing (stories, novels, books, screenplays, etc.) for hundreds of years, and yet we continue to say "so-and-so wrote a (story/novel/book/screenplay)"; we do not have a need to say

> <sup>*</sup>I storyated that idea.  *-or-*
>   <sup>*</sup>John bookified my funny story.

I would stick with "I wrote an API for (something)".

Comment: Uh, [novelize](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/novelize) is a recognized word.

Comment: @HotLicks So it is!  example changed.